# Can java be used as a server side language for a website?

Tags: java, server-side

Hypothetically, could java be used to write a website instead of, say, asp.net. or php?

Comment: JSP, Servlet.  Google those terms.

Comment: Those links may be helpful: [What's the Java alternative to ASP.NET/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556553), [Analogues of Java and .NET technologies.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526024) [Java webdev, what skills do I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808), [JSP tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [Servlets tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info). As to erickson's comment, it was just sarcasm :) Guess what Google uses under the covers.

Comment: @everyone - Ok... this is what i know about Java... It's used to write android apps, and the syntax is similar to C# (or vice versa) I am considering learning it and I was simply wondering what the other benefits of learning java could be... I already new about java applets... . I just wanted to know if Java had a web framework similar to .NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J2EE is an entire branch of Java made towards running Java as a web server.  It includes making it easy to code for distributed servers, a messaging protocol and database interaction.  It's extremely powerful, well written and stable and you'll find it's used by many large web sites.

It's also very different from just coding a simple single-purpose server.  Some of the complication is up-front/built in, so there is a larger initial learning curve but you won't encounter many of the problems you would if you tried to do it on your own...

For instance, imagine the most complex server-side code you've written--what would it take to make it run distributed across 2 servers (So that either server may answer any request with the requests based on server load)?  If it were written in proper J2EE it would just be editing a few config files.

Answer (score 5):

Some would argue that this is what Java is **mostly** used for! Sarcasm aside check out the Wikipedia entry for [**Java Enterprise Edition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) for the summary and of course the official [**Oracle Java EE**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) website for details.

Basically there is a whole host of mature server APIs and application servers from different vendors (including Open Source vendors) that implement those APIs. Server side Java is really a mini-industry with god knows how many companies, open source projects, conferences and the like.

If you are new to server side Java you coming in at a good time, you missed the dark days [**EJB 1.0 and 1.1**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean#Rapid_adoption_followed_by_criticism) and now there is a rather useful, if a little heavyweight set of APIs on which to build your server side applications.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is actually quite common.

Answer (score 0):

I think so. It's the basis for JSP and Java Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can use Tomcat web container or glass fish, JBoss,...
There is few frameworks, like Tapestry, JSF,...

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered a .jsp extension for a page, it was definitely Java (.jsp = Java Server Pages). Of course you can generate plain HTML (or whatever you want) as well.

Comment: Doesn't JSP generate "plain HTML" (and Javascript and CSS)?

Comment: That is true with PHP or Perl or any scripting language. It is what you write that makes it different. If I have PHP do `echo 'hello';` it is plain text. If I have it do `echo '<style type="text/css">body { background-image: url(some_image); }</style>';` it is generating CSS.