# Moving from ASP.NET to JSP

Tags: jsp

I have been working for about 5 years now on ASP.NET  and C# and have worked all versions of .NET.Recently moved to a firm that uses ASP.NET as well as JSP and MYSQL.How hard will it be to start JSP learning from scratch ? Any documentation which shows some relation between functions/ syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't imagine any non-trivial JSP project without requiring you to learn Java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526024/analogues-of-java-and-net-technologies-frameworks/2526138#2526138) with analogues of Java and .NET technologies/frameworks

Answer (score 1):

JSP is really more similar to "classic" ASP than ASP.NET. For instance, see this: http://www.daysite.net/programming/jsp.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're a smart developer, you won't have any problems switching between the two.

As far as relations between syntax and functions, my recommendation is do a quick google search for them and if it doesn't work out for you, post a question on SO - that's the kind of question that gets gobbled up in about 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596005407](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005407). I found it very helpful while learning JSP.