# Java Equivalent for ASP.NET MVC Areas

Tags: java, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-areas

Areas, in ASP.NET MVC, are handy for breaking a site into smaller, manageable components at a higher level than controllers.  They are like mini-MVC pieces within a web application.

Is there an equivalent concept in any Java MVC framework to ASP.NET Areas?

If not, are there any suggestions on best practices when emulating their functionality in a Java MVC framework?

Comment: See also list of other .NET <-> Java equivalencies. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2526024/55452

Answer (score 2):

Try [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/). This may be fulfill your wish.

Answer (score 0):

Look at JSP Tiles and Velocity Templates. Tiles should look similiar to Areas.

Answer (score 0):

As such, Java EE does not provide an out of box solution based on MVC but there are many OpenSource projects that have created a solution which implement a MVC framework - try the latest Spring and Struts versions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this Web Framework for java: [playframework](http://www.playframework.com/)