# Corresponding features between .NET and Java EE

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Can you tell me which components of .NET are the corresponding with beans (Entity Bean, Sessionbean, Message Driven Bean) of Java EE?

Comment: You can find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526024/analogues-of-java-and-net-technologies-frameworks)