# .Net and Java EE approaches when it comes to "Application Servers"

Tags: asp.net, .net, jakarta-ee, application-server

Disclaimer : *This is a general question regarding App Servers, not a specific programming question. If this is not the right forum for it please redirect me to the right place.*

I have equal experience in both Java & .Net technologies, and I have the impression that the approaches are radically different when it comes to Application Servers. In the Java World, App Servers cover a broad range of services and features, whereas .Net has IIS (*very* roughly equivalent to Apache/Tomcat) in one hand, and Windows OS itself to handle some specific tasks (Services for Examples), plus the .Net framework itself consisting in different boutique modules.

This may explain why Java Application Servers *may* appear somehow "massive" to a regular .Net developer, as much of the load managed by the App Servers in Java EE is an integrated part of Windows Server OS itself.

The usual issues seem to be tackled very differently between the two platforms, making it hard to really compare the features offered by any Java EE App Servers to a .Net Architecture, on a side-by-side basis.

Is this vision roughly correct or am I missing something ?

Sorry in advance if my question is not clear enough, but you I hope you get the idea.

Comment: IIS is a generic web server, not simply an app server. It handles things such as resource allocation and the low level functions required to serve an application. After that, it's up to the application to service the requests that IIS passes along.

Comment: Agreed. That is why I compared IIS to Apache/Tomcat and not to an App Server per se

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding what answer exactly you are expecting. This? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096 Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2526024